# Android Graphical Layout Editor in eclipse can't see my custom class

Tags: android

I have created a new class that extends the RelativeLayout and when viewing this using the Grahical Layout editor, I always see this error:

The following classes could not be found:
- eg.package.StripedBackgroundLayout

Has anyone experience this before and how to resolve it please?

I'm using ADT 12.0.0

Comment: which version of adt are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you currently cannot resolve this. The Graphical Layout Editor is not equipped to handle custom classes at the moment. It can be achieved with some hefty modification, but it isn't worth the time. It will be included in later Graphical Layout editor updates.

Comment: The funny thing is if I open the ApiDemos sample project and I placed my class there and create a new layout/or modify the custom_view_1.xml, then I can my custom class rendering and don't see that error. However, if I try this on my project, it shows that error.

Comment: Hah yeah. It's sort of a hit or miss right now. If you define the XML attribute constructor for the custom class, it should always work in theory, but its iffy right now.

Answer (score 0):

Another funny thing about eclipse is that, when I we open the graphical layout view for the first time it shows your custom view's when you clear the project.. till any modification in layout, then you just need to clear it again.